# i have a problem with my aplication invalid argument suplied for foreach

Tags: codeigniter

Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Soal extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['judul'] = 'Halaman Ujian';
        $this->load->view('templates/header_cover', $data);
        $this->load->view('soal/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    public function tampil_soal()
    {
        $this->load->model('soalmodel');
        $this->data['tanya'] = $this->soalmodel->getPertanyaan();
        $this->load->view('soal', $this->data);
    }
}
```

```
Filename: soal/index.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\application\views\soal\index.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\application\controllers\Soal.php
Line: 11
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: soal/index.php

Line Number: 23

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\application\views\soal\index.php
Line: 23
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\application\controllers\Soal.php
Line: 11
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\TA\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: show us your controller code to check

Comment: i must show my code twice, case to much code.

Comment: 1. <?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Soal extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $data['judul'] = 'Halaman Ujian';
        $this->load->view('templates/header_cover', $data);
        $this->load->view('soal/index');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

Comment: 2. function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    public function tampil_soal()
    {
        $this->load->model('soalmodel');
        $this->data['tanya'] = $this->soalmodel->getPertanyaan();
        $this->load->view('soal', $this->data);
    }
}

Comment: ^nobody can read that. put the code in the question itself and properly format it. read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Your question should include *relevant* parts of your **model/view/controller**. Please note, the error you are getting is mostlikely due to a query failing or there being no rows!

Comment: can you share your view in which you are using foreach()?

Comment: yes i wil show you brother.

Comment: i write my code i answer bellow guys, sorry cause if i write in this comment too long character.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php $ans_araay = array($row->pilihan1, $row->pilihan2, $row->pilihan3, $row->jawaban);
    shuffle($ans_araay); ?>

    <p>
        <?= $row->id_soal ?>.<?= $row->pertanyaan ?>
    </p>

    <input type="radio" name="idsoal<?= $row->id_soal ?>" value="<?= $ans_araay[0] ?>"> <?= $ans_araay[0] ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="idsoal<?= $row->id_soal ?>" value="<?= $ans_araay[1] ?>"> <?= $ans_araay[1] ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="idsoal<?= $row->id_soal ?>" value="<?= $ans_araay[2] ?>"> <?= $ans_araay[2] ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="idsoal<?= $row->id_soal ?>" value="<?= $ans_araay[3] ?>"> <?= $ans_araay[3] ?><br>
<?php
```

}
?>